# Meaning of a joke in the Big Bang Theory: "when your locus coeruleus sits around the house, it sits around the house"

Tags: meaning, prepositions, jokes

In the Big Bang Theory, Season 5, Episode 16, The Vacation Solution:

> Amy: Okay, smart guy. I'm about to remove the locus coeruleus, which is incredibly delicate work. Have at it.
>
> Sheldon: All right. I'm no stranger to a little gray matter. Locus coeruleus. Locus coeruleus.
>
> Amy: You're getting warmer, it is, indeed, in the brain. Hope your hands are steady. It's the width of a single hair. But this is just biology, so I'm sure it's no problem for a genius like you.
>
> Sheldon: It's not. I'll have you know, in the field of physics, we work with particles so small, they make fat jokes about the locus coeruleus, i.e., **when your locus coeruleus sits around the house, it sits around the house.**

The above is a joke in the Big Bang Theory, I can't understand the bold sentence:  when your locus coeruleus sits around the house, it sits around the house. Could you explain to me what's the meaning?

Comment: Perhaps a form of exaggeration. It *encompasses* the house? When it sits around the house (acts lazy) it sits around (encompasses) the house.

Comment: Laurel’s answer provides the two meanings used in the joke, but this is a stock joke probably going back to vaudeville tradition. “My wife is so fat” (Stock audience response: “How fat is she?”) “Well, when she sits around the house, she really sits *around* the house”. Needless to say it’s considered poor taste today, but that’s part of the joke that the writers were making with Sheldon.

Comment: @BenMurphy and that was revitalized in the 90s with the "yo mama's so x" jokes, which I am hoping is dead and forgotten now.

Comment: You must have it wrong -- Sheldon would never confuse i.e.with e.g.!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first time, he's using "sit around" to mean

> to sit somewhere and do nothing or do nothing in particular:
>
> > He just sits around the house watching TV.
>
> ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sit-around))

The second time, he's playing on a different meaning of "sit around": to encircle. (I believe he also emphasizes the word "around" to indicate where the wordplay is.) This is a fat joke, so that's saying that the locus coeruleus is so big it could fit around a house. Here's the relevant definition from [McGraw-Hill via TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sit+around):

> to be seated at the edge or perimeter of something.
>
> > They sat around the camp fire for hours. We used to sit around the big kitchen table and talk.

This joke predates the Big Bang Theory. The earliest example I found was in the [1963 TV Guide](https://www.google.com/books/edition/TV_Guide/DVdNpEqkGhUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22sits%20around%20the%20house%22):

> For instance, if somebody hollered "fat," Morey [Amsterdam] might crack, "My uncle is so fat that when he sits around the house he sits around the house."

Comment: Right, it's an old joke, they made it "geeky" by using a technical term for part of the brain.